# How to add "@odata.deltaLink" in the response using ASP.NET Web API solution

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

My Odata service url : https://odataservices.azurewebsites.net/People

Response:

{"@odata.context":"https://odataservices.azurewebsites.net/$metadata#People","value":[{"ID":"001","Name":"Angel","Description":null},{"ID":"002","Name":"Clyde","Description":"Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text."},{"ID":"003","Name":"Kunal","Description":"It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making Lorems over 2000 years old."},{"ID":"004","Name":"tejas","Description":"It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making Lorems over 2000 years old."}]}

I would like to add "@odata.deltaLink" as a another property in the response which would contain links for the incremental changes.

How would i do that in ASP.NET Web API solution?

Answer (score 0):

The user can obtain a delta link from each entity API in the library by including the odata.track-changes preference in the header of the request. The response to the GET request returns a deltaLink parameter, providing an opaque URL.

See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-connect-apps-delta

Comment: Do you have any working sample of delta link using .net web api solutions ??